# Black Screen when i name my classes in Story Boards

Tags: ios, iphone, ios5, ios4

Im using story boards and in the Custom Class panel of the specific view controller if i give the name of the class that contains code for that view controller i get a blank screen. What could be the problem? Ive tried everything.

SO basically Class is usually UIViewController in CustomClass. I changed it to MenuScreenViewController(a ViewController objective C class that has code associated with this) and im calling it modally. Why do i get a blank screen. Urgent help please.

Comment: There is no code involved unfortunately. Its in the UI editor on the storyboard. The code is the custom code that you see when you create a new view controller in xcode. However in the UI i have added buttons. and these buttons appear when i say UIViewController in place of MenuScreenViewController. :(

Comment: Okay, and just for clarity sake, when you say custom class for a specific view controller, are you by any chance referring to a custom segue controller? If not, I don't mean to be condescending, I just want to have a clear understanding of the situation to help you better.

Comment: No i am not referring to a custom seque controller. SO basically in my project structure I have stuff like AppDelegate.h/m etc etc and with that I also have a class called MenuScreenView (Which at the moment has nothing apart from the code that comes with it when created however i edited the orientation of the device there). Now in the storyboard UI i click on the viewcontroller and in the side panel where you can customize ur view there is something called class under the custom class section. This is by default UIViewController but i changed it to menuscreenViewcontroller but that doesn work

Comment: I however do know that it goes into that class because i have a print statement printing from the menuscreenviewcontroller class so it does go there but i just get a blak screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess, once again:

remove the implementation of `- (void)loadView` from your UIViewController subclass. You only need this method when you create your viewControllers view in code. When you create the view from a nib file or storyboard you must not have this method.

But it's not your fault, the implementation is there because of a bug in the Xcode 4.3 viewController templates.

EDIT: This bug is fixed in Xcode 4.3.2. The template does no longer contain `- (void)loadView`