# Ios simulator giving me a black screen when trying to load storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have been trying to solve this problem for over 14 hours now...I am really hoping that someone could please help me load my storyboard. Everytime I try it non-programmatically, it decides it wants to keep it as a black screen (and its not the loading screen. I checked to see if it was in the initial view controller. Yet nothing. So I figure, maybe I need to do it programmatically. I've synthesized them properly as you can see. Still nothing. What am I doing wrong (there is no xcode error output).

Appdelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class ViewController;
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate> {
        UIWindow *window;
    UIViewController *viewController;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIViewController *viewController;
@end
```

AppDelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "ViewController.h"


@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window;
@synthesize viewController=_viewController;
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc]
                   initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

self.window.rootViewController = viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Save data if appropriate
}
```

Comment: are you using Xcode 4.3.1? Or UIViewController subclasses that have been created with this version? Upgrade to the latest version and check for [`- (void)loadView`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9669995/black-screen-when-i-name-my-classes-in-story-boards/9670361#9670361)

Comment: Can we remove this @property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window; from the .h?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are using a Storyboard, you should remove the code you have written in the app delegate method; change it to look like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    return YES;
}
```

Next look at your build target properties (in your project navigator, click on the name of your project at the very top).  Is your storyboard selected in the "Main Storyboard" section of the "Summary" pane?

Finally go to the storyboard and make sure your view controller is selected as the initial view controller. Select the view controller scene and verify that the "Initial Scene: Is Initial View Controller" box in the attributes inspector pane is checked.

If all of these steps have been verified and you're still seeing a blank screen, it's possible that there is a bug in your view controller.  Try dragging a brand new view controller to the storyboard, add a label, and set it as the initial view controller.  If you are able to see that scene launch, there is a problem with your original view controller (rather than it being  an issue with the launching of your storyboard).

Comment: Alright, so I removed the code like you said, but that now gives me the error "attempt to load view controller that is not in the view hierarchy"? It must be the problem. What should I do for that?

Comment: [6553:c07] Warning: Attempt to present <LoginScreen: 0x7177610> on <ViewController: 0x7170850> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Comment: @user1776234 Ok, so is this for the first view controller or second? When you start up your app are you able to see the initial scene or does this error happen right away?

Comment: Thanks so far. I am able to see the initial scene, but I am not able to pull up the login screen when needed with a segue. To switch between the two, I am calling     if (![[API sharedInstance] isAuthorized]) {
  [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowLogin" sender:nil]; I have just asked a question with my entire source code here plus your app delegate corrections: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13091643/view-controller-not-in-view-hierarchy

Answer (score 1):

First of all your `viewController` property is just a nil, it's not initialized anywhere. With this `self.window.rootViewController = viewController;` you just pass nil to `rootViewController`.

In Interface Builder you should have arrow indicating your initial view controller - as seen on this [picture](http://cdn2.raywenderlich.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/Initial-arrow-394x500.png) or in Attributes Inspector as seen [here](http://cdn1.raywenderlich.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/Is-Initial-View-Controller-attribute.png)

You may also read excellent tutorial on storyboards [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1)